# Need to create overlapping week range selections for a PBI slicer

Tags: switch-statement, dax, var, date-range, slicers

I have a sales dashboard that needs to have slicer options for "Last 4 Weeks", "Last 13 Weeks", etc. The company has weeks that start on Saturday and a fiscal calendar that starts in Feb, so many of the auto time logic in PBI does not work correctly.

[MThe calendar table does have a week sequence and a column that labels the "CURRENT" week. So I built a week index that counts backwards from the current week.

[image]

I've built a variable and switch statement to that plays off of the count back column to filter to the range of weeks. But when I write the "`IN filter(calendar,calendar[week count back]>0 && calendar[week count back]<=4)`" it gives me an error "The number of arguments is invalid. Function CONTAINSROW must have a value for each column in the table expression.". I've looked up some very similar codes that worked fine with the same build and have tried a number of variations on this code block.

Here is my current variable and switch statement. I have this connected to a custom table with the selection list.

```
WkRangeSelection = 
 
VAR myselection = SELECTEDVALUE('Time Selection'[Period])
    VAR Current_WK = MAX(retailers_calandar_wk[Wk_CountBack]) IN FILTER(retailers_calandar_wk,retailers_calandar_wk[Wk_CountBack]=0)
    VAR Last_WK = MIN(retailers_calandar_wk[Wk_CountBack]) IN FILTER(retailers_calandar_wk,retailers_calandar_wk[Wk_CountBack]=1)
    VAR Last_4_Weeks = MAX(retailers_calandar[Last4WeeksCheck]) IN FILTER(retailers_calandar_wk,retailers_calandar_wk[Wk_CountBack] > 1 && retailers_calandar_wk[Wk_CountBack] <= 4)
    VAR Last_13_Weeks = MAX(retailers_calandar[Last13WeeksCheck]) IN FILTER(retailers_calandar_wk,retailers_calandar_wk[Wk_CountBack] > 1 && retailers_calandar_wk[Wk_CountBack] <= 13)
    VAR Last_52_Weeks = MAX(retailers_calandar[Last52WeeksCheck]) IN FILTER(retailers_calandar_wk,retailers_calandar_wk[Wk_CountBack] > 1 && retailers_calandar_wk[Wk_CountBack] <= 52)
    
RETURN
    int(SWITCH(
        myselection,  1, Current_WK,
                      2, Last_WK,
                      3, Last_4_Weeks,
                      4, Last_13_Weeks,
                      5, Last_52_Weeks
        ))
```

I am open to solutions to the above method or to any other possible paths to the slicer I need. Thanks!

Comment: the final argument for the YTD functions is the last date of the fiscal year... e.g. TOTALYTD( 'Table'[NumericColumn], '6/30')
And did you see this? https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Community-Blog/STARTOFWEEK-and-ENDOFWEEK-functions-in-DAX/ba-p/2519918